# Dataframe chaining operations to update a column using values from another column with specific condition

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with following schema

| timestamp | uuid | row_id | row_num | col_id | col_num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7/28 10:30 | abc123 | aaa | 1 | zzz567 | 1 |
| 7/28 10:30 | abc123 | aaa | 1 | zzz568 | 2 |
| 7/28 10:30 | abc123 | aaa | 1 | zzz569 | 3 |
| 7/28 10:30 | abc123 | aaa | null | zzz570 | 4 |
| 7/28 10:30 | abc123 | aaa | null | zzz571 | 5 |
| 7/28 10:30 | abc123 | bbb | 2 | yyy567 | 1 |
| 7/28 10:30 | abc123 | bbb | 2 | yyy568 | 2 |
| 7/28 10:30 | abc123 | bbb | 2 | yyy569 | 3 |
| 7/28 10:30 | abc123 | bbb | null | yyy570 | 4 |

Now, row num is always null when col num goes above > 3. In cases like these, I would want to impute those null row numbers with the first non-null row number value for that row id. So my output should essentially look like

| timestamp | uuid | row_id | row_num | col_id | col_num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7/28 10:30 | abc123 | aaa | 1 | zzz567 | 1 |
| 7/28 10:30 | abc123 | aaa | 1 | zzz568 | 2 |
| 7/28 10:30 | abc123 | aaa | 1 | zzz569 | 3 |
| 7/28 10:30 | abc123 | aaa | **1** | zzz570 | 4 |
| 7/28 10:30 | abc123 | aaa | **1** | zzz571 | 5 |
| 7/28 10:30 | abc123 | bbb | 2 | yyy567 | 1 |
| 7/28 10:30 | abc123 | bbb | 2 | yyy568 | 2 |
| 7/28 10:30 | abc123 | bbb | 2 | yyy569 | 3 |
| 7/28 10:30 | abc123 | bbb | **2** | yyy570 | 4 |

I'm trying to do this using row_number and withColumn functions (I'm on Spark 2.2, so can't use nth_value function). I'm trying to do something like

```
df \
.withColumn('rn', F.row_number() \
.over(Window.partitionBy'uuid', 'row_id') \
.orderBy('timestamp', 'row_num'))) \
.withColumn('imputed_row_num', F.when((F.col('row_id').isNotNull() & 
F.col('row_num').isNull()), df.filter(df.rn == 1).row_num) \
.otherwise(F.col('row_num')))
```

But this throws an error saying rn is not defined. I'm aware this could be done through join, however, wanted to check if it's also possible to get the deried results with chaining operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `last` with `true` as second parameter (which is to ignore nulls), so:

```
.withColumn("new", expr("last(row_num, true) over (partition by uuid,row_id order by timestamp)"))
```

will create a new column called `new` that holds that last non-null value from column `row_num`.

Next, we overwrite `row_num` column if the value is null with the value from `new` column:

```
.withColumn("row_num",
    when(col("row_num").isNull, col("new")).otherwise(col("row_num"))
)
```

We finally drop `new` column:

```
.drop("new")
```

Final output (without specific ordering):

```
+----------+------+------+-------+------+-------+
| timestamp|  uuid|row_id|row_num|col_id|col_num|
+----------+------+------+-------+------+-------+
|7/28 10:30|abc123|   bbb|      2|yyy567|      1|
|7/28 10:30|abc123|   bbb|      2|yyy567|      2|
|7/28 10:30|abc123|   bbb|      2|yyy567|      3|
|7/28 10:30|abc123|   bbb|      2|yyy567|      4|
|7/28 10:30|abc123|   aaa|      1|zzz567|      1|
|7/28 10:30|abc123|   aaa|      1|zzz567|      2|
|7/28 10:30|abc123|   aaa|      1|zzz567|      3|
|7/28 10:30|abc123|   aaa|      1|zzz567|      4|
|7/28 10:30|abc123|   aaa|      1|zzz567|      5|
+----------+------+------+-------+------+-------+
```